# How to change the color for Elpy autocomplete box and not display the private variables first

Tags: python, text, emacs, autocomplete, ide

I'm trying to get Emacs 24.3.1 running on Ubuntu 14.04 configured for Python development and am using [elpy](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy) for autocompletion. There are currently two problems I'm facing. Both can be seen in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot].

The color scheme is very difficult to work with and the private methods always appear first in the list.

The relevant lines in my emacs init are:

```
;;pop-ups                                                                                             
(require 'popup)

;;;python-mode                                                                                        
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("elpy" . "http://jorgenschaefer.github.io/packages/"))
(elpy-enable)
;; Fixing a key binding bug in elpy                                                                   
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c k") 'yas-expand)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c o") 'iedit-mode)
;;Use jedi for autocomplete                                                                           
(setq elpy-rpc-backend "jedi")

(setq py-install-directory "~/.emacs.d/python-mode.el-6.1.3")
(add-to-list 'load-path py-install-directory)
(require 'python-mode)

; use IPython                                                                                         
(setq-default py-shell-name "ipython")
(setq-default py-which-bufname "IPython")
; use the wx backend, for both mayavi and matplotlib                                                  
(setq py-python-command-args
  '("--gui=wx" "--pylab=wx" "-colors" "Linux"))
(setq py-force-py-shell-name-p t)

; switch to the interpreter after executing code                                                      
(setq py-shell-switch-buffers-on-execute-p t)
(setq py-switch-buffers-on-execute-p t)
; don't split windows                                                                                 
(setq py-split-windows-on-execute-p nil)
; try to automagically figure out indentation                                                         
(setq py-smart-indentation t)
;; Jedi backend                                                                                       
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t) ;optional                                                               
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'auto-complete-mode)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:ac-setup)
```

Any help with either of these issues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The color theme is the same as used by the completion method Elpy uses. If you upgraded to the current release of 1.5.1, that would be `company-mode`. In theory, this should already work correctly with a dark-background Emacs. Try setting `frame-background-mode` to `dark` first — maybe Emacs did not detect your background correctly (though it should). If that fails, you can change the colors ("faces") it uses by doing `M-x customize-group RET company RET` and look for options with "face" in their name.

Changing the order of the completions is a bit more tricky and would require changing some code within Elpy. I created [an issue](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/321) for this request.